# Hovering over only on selected Images

Tags: html, css

**I just want to make the images blur when I hover over it.**
**Please check the image for better understanding of my subject**

I usually take hours to make a simple page so I have to totally depend on google to find codes but now even google and code-pen are not getting the solution so if I can get the solution then it will be a great help.

[image]

This is my code
https://codepen.io/yogesh-patgar/pen/zYYgJLO

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.row:hover .column:hover {
  filter: blur(3px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.row:hover .column {
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: blur(0px);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your [mcve] code, the HTML and CSS, that you're working with so we can reproduce your problem, and then you need to explain - clearly - what you're trying to do, what you hope to achieve and where you're currently stuck and/or what's going wrong with your own attempts. Please: take a look at the [tour], and read about "*[ask]*"

Comment: You can refer to this example: https://codepen.io/mcraig218/pen/uqIae

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "lane" and what is the desire for the statement "then the other 4 images of that lane."

Comment: Sorry i will post my code in an hour..Thanks

Comment: The edited code is starting to make sense, so at least there's that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem might be that you are trying to blur the whole row/column instead of the image itself.

You're doing

`.column:hover{ transform:blur(3px) }` instead of

`.column img:hover{ transform:blur(3px) }`.

If that's the problem, this would be the fix: https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/zYYgMZW

If what you're aming at is also having some text, then you need a container for the text and image, and you should trigger changes when the container is hovered (in this case `<div class="div-with-image-and-text">`) https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/rNNXQLG

UPDATE:

After author's latest comment, I think they are trying to achieve the blur over multiple images in the same "box". As such, I just made a new set of rows and columns inside each blurring container:

https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/rNNXQpd

Comment: No I want to  blur 4 images at once when i hover over it...I mean  images should get blurred in that box which i have shown in the link so there will be 4 boxes with set of images when i hover over it gets blurred...but images should be in the way like the pic which i attached..

Comment: Oh. The problem then, is that you need to have multiple images in the same container, therefore creating another grid inside the grid.

Comment: Ok @RandomNoobDeveloper Is this latest codepen what you are trying to do? Only modified the first square for the demo, but the idea is you can have multiple images in the `div-with-image-and-text` that has the hover effect

Comment: Yes i need a hover effect in every container

Comment: I didn't get ur last comment @paul Ghiran

Comment: I updated the answer. Look at this pen. It's an example with the first "box" having blur over 4 images instead of one. If this is it, you can just use the same structure.

https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/rNNXQpd

Comment: Ohh Thank You Very much @Paul Ghiran!!

Comment: If this was your solution, please mark this as the "Accepted answer"